# Convert format all images in imagemagick subfolders

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a folder with pictures and subfolders I'm trying to reduce the size of the pictures in the subfolders and Lossless compression and convert them to jpg 2000

Which I used

```
find ./static/assets/images/* -name '*.png' | xargs mogrify -strip
```

It works fine, but I don't know how to change the image format.

Comment: Try `find ./static/assets/images/* -name '*.png' | xargs mogrify -format jp2 -strip`

Comment: It was a problem with the version. Thank you